# How do I enable SSL in Cherokee without libcherokee-mod-ssl?

Tags: webserver, ssl

I am trying to enable HTTPS support in my Cherokee webserver, but the option to enable it is missing from the "General" tab in the admin web interface. The back-end drop down only contains the "No TLS/SSL" option.

After a little searching, I found a few mentions of the `libcherokee-mod-libssl` package, which seems to be what I need to install. But [it only exists in 10.04, 11.10 and 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcherokee-mod-libssl), not 12.10. Trying a direct `apt-get install` gives the following:

```
josh@sirius:~$ sudo apt-get install libcherokee-mod-libssl
[sudo] password for josh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libcherokee-mod-libssl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libcherokee-mod-libssl' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked their [installation guide](http://www.cherokee-project.com/downloads.html)? There you can find a PPA (i guess maintained by Cherokee Team) that provides Cherokee and the package you need.

So, if using a PPA is an option, just follow those instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cherokee-webserver/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcherokee-mod-libssl
```

Good luck!